# how to add Navigation Drawer in android app in minimum size

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hello friends i am new developer in android, am trying to making android app in minimum size and my app size is maximum 100 KB. The problem is when i adding `navigation drawer` in my app then app size is `increased into 2 MB`.

so anyone can suggest me how to add `Navigation Drawer` in android app in minimum size.

Comment: Are you using any library or optimization?

Answer (score 0):

After completing your project, Click on **Build** --> then select **Clean Project**
This will remove all unnecessary files which will reduce APK size.